# RRule for Recurring events is common across all platforms?

Tags: calendar, cross-platform, recurrence, rfc, rrule

Whether the standardisation and conventions in RRule for generating recurring events in calendar is unique?

I mean whether the same rule can be used in all the platforms like Android, iOS and Windows.

**EDITED:**

So my questions are

1. Can use the same RRule for all the platforms?
2. If not, suggest me the standards for each platform

**ADDED:**
Can i add use the below RRULE standard in all the platforms.

[KB about RRULE - RecurrenceRule by Syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/3719/what-is-the-recurrencerule-in-schedule-control)

Comment: i have already narrow down my question in the Edited content, but still there are some votes to close this question :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RRULE property is defined by [RFC5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545) and as such is totally platform agnostic. Now, of course:

- there exist multiple implementations of the standard, each of them with their own restrictions or bugs.
- the RRULE definition itself may be ambiguous on certain aspects, leading to multiple interpretations.

Please note that it is not so much a question of platform than a question of implementation. You may have 2 implementations on different platforms that interoperate very well, and you can have 2 implementations on the same platform that do not interoperate.

Answer (score 0):

`RFC2445`  and `RFC5445` protocols were used to create `*.ical` file formats.
 [As per wiki](http://[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar]%20,)
iCalendar (`*.ics`) is used and supported by a large number of products, including `Google Calendar`, `Apple Calendar` (formerly iCal), `IBM Lotus Notes`,`Yahoo! Calendar`, `Evolution (software)`, `eM Client`, `Lightning extension for Mozilla Thunderbird` and `SeaMonkey`, and partially by `Microsoft Outlook` and `Novell GroupWise`.

We need to use the same protocols while implementing Recurrence engine also,

As per wiki, `RFC 5545` replaced `RFC 2445` in September 2009 and now defines the standard.

So i guess it is not platform specific, so we can use the same protocol in all the platforms.

Any comment or suggestions on this is highly appreciable